# How can i capture a specific column of data with .Net regex when some columns may be empty?

Tags: .net, regex

I am currently capturing data with .net version of regex (Using Expresso), and I have some code that works for a lot of the columns, but not in some. I believe the problem is that one of the beginning columns is empty in some cases:

```
A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L   M   N   O   P   Q   R   S   T
USER 1  USER 2  USER 3  USER 4  USER 5  General General General General M.O.L.E.(r) M.O.L.E.(r) Oven    Oven    Oven AMB    Oven AMB    Oven AMB
one 14  Zone 14 Zone 14 Zone 14 Zone 14 Zone 14 Zone 15 Zone 15 Zone 15 Zone 15 Zone 15 Zone 15 Zone 15 Zone 16 Zone 16 Zone 16 Zone 16 Zone 16 Zone 16
All All All All All All All All All All All All All All
Pass (Overnrider) NJH 12/7/2015                 SMG20-27527 (OvenRider) 12/07/2015  07:59:16    OR_FCT_ENTRY_000561 34.0    4.863   15  101.17  24.4    23.9
Pass (Rework) NJH 11/25/2015                    SMG20-27641 (Rework)    11/25/2015  11:46:43    OR_FCT_ENTRY_000560 31.0    4.863   15  100.60  21.7    21.1
Passed (Rework Mole) RH 11/17/2015                  SMG20-27641 (Rework)    11/17/2015  18:35:48    OR_FCT_ENTRY_000558 33.0    4.893   15  100.60  23.3
Pass (Overnrider) NJH 12/7/2015                 SMG20-27527 (OvenRider) 12/07/2015  07:59:16    OR_FCT_ENTRY_000561 34.0    4.863   15  101.17  24.4    23.9
Pass (Rework) NJH 11/25/2015                    SMG20-27641 (Rework)    11/25/2015  11:46:43    OR_FCT_ENTRY_000560 31.0    4.863   15  100.60  21.7    21.1
Passed (Rework Mole) RH 11/17/2015                  SMG20-27641 (Rework)    11/17/2015  18:35:48    OR_FCT_ENTRY_000558 33.0    4.893   15  100.60  23.3
```

the regex i am currently using is:

```
^(?:([^\s\n]+)\s+){13}
```

and the result is:

```
101.17
100.6
15
100.6
4.893
```

how can i ensure that the data i am capturing is always in the 100.XX row like below(Row H)?

```
101.17
100.6
101.7
100.6
100.6
```

FYI this is pulled from excel into a notepad doc...

Comment: You should just read directly from the Excel file if possible. If not, your life will be much easier if you save or export the Excel sheet as a CSV file. Failing that, try using a text editor like Notepad++ (or whatever) to insert commas (replace `tab` character with "`tab`,"), or just append a delimiter character (`,`,`;`,`|`,whatever) to each column before copying it out.

Comment: It seems you have tab separated values. How about splitting on tabs and retrieving the desired column?

Comment: @Mariano they are tab separated, but, if a few lines have data in Column "A", and some do not, wouldn't that mess up my capture?

Comment: In the text you pasted, some lines are tab separated and some are not. Please verify you're pasting the exact text you're reading. It is not clear if you want all values from column H or only those that match a pattern. Please create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

It isn't that there are empty columns, it's that some of the columns may contain spaces.  Specifically, `(Rework Mole)` is supposed to be one field, but your regex treats it as two.  You need to look for one of two things: a field enclosed in parentheses, or a sequence of non-whitespace characters.  This regex yields the desired results:

```
^(?:(\([^()]+\)|\S+) +){13}
```

Note that `\s` matches all kinds of whitespace, including newlines.  The delimiters are just spaces, so it's best to match just those.